# Function to hide a div when application(value) = 1

Tags: jquery, vbscript

I have a page written in VBscript. Based on a value I need to call a JQuery function to hide  and disaply . How would I go about this? All I can seem to find are examples where functions are called on user input[eg. .click]. Any tutorials or example code would be awesome.

```
<% if application("value") = 1 then %>
call jquery to hide <div class="default"> and disaply <div class="question"> 
<%else if %> 
<div class="default">
<%end if%>
```

Comment: I think you are talking about server-side vbScript, right?

Answer (score 1):

Something like... ?

```
<% if application("value") = 1 then %> 
    $('div.something').show();
<%else if application("value") = 2 then %>
    $('div.something').hide();
<%end if%>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

To hide you can say:

```
jQuery("#mydiv").hide();
```

The [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) is a great reference, especially for this kind of thing.

But we need more information to figure out how to disapply. What type of HTML element are you working with, and what exactly are you trying to do?

Also, more importantly, since the vbScript would execute server-side, you could just code all of this up in vbScript. Unless there is some dynamic event happening on the client that you did not include in your question... :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

vbScript:

```
<% if application("value") = 1 then %> hideDiv() <%else if %> <%end if%>
```

JavaScript:

```
var hideDiv = function(){
$("#myDiv").hide();
};
```

I read somewhere that vbscript & javascript functions can be called from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use javaScript to solve your problem (Its a pure Java Script Solution without jQuery)

**JS Script**

```
function showHidden() {

if (document.getElementById("formId").style.display != none) {
    document.getElementById("formId").style.display = "none";
 }else{
    document.getElementById("formId").style.display = "block";
 }

}
```

**The Form**

and somewhere call the function with event onchange="showHidden()" inside some tag, it can be `<select onchange="showHidden()" >` or whatever tag.

```
<div id="formId" style="display:none">
 ... the content ...
</div>
```

I hope it helps